# Blinding a message with PyCrypto in Python 3+

Tags: python, cryptography, pycrypto, blind-signature

In Python 2, there were two methods called blind/unblind. Their docs recommend that you should now use `pkcs1_15`, however they only show how to sign/verify a message.

Their sample code looks like this:

```
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

# Generate a new RSA key pair
private_key = RSA.generate(3072)
public_key = private_key.publickey()

# Message which is larger than the modulus
message = 'Some arbitrary text to blind.'
message = message.encode('utf-8')
hashed_message = SHA256.new(message)

# Sign message on the senders side
signed_message = pkcs1_15.new(private_key).sign(hashed_message)

# On the receivers' side, you can verify the signed message with the public key
pkcs1_15.new(public_key).verify(hashed_message, signed_message)

# No exceptions raised, so we can conclude that the signature is valid.
```

Does anyone know what the code would look like, if one were to blind it instead?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic on Crypto SE, even if they are about cryptographic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: PyCrypto is [no longer maintained](https://www.pycrypto.org/), and one should use its mostly-API-compatible successor, [PyCryptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/), instead. If one is willing to learn a new API, they even advocate to switch to the [Cryptography](https://cryptography.io) library instead.

According to their documentation, they [fully dropped](https://www.pycryptodome.org/src/vs_pycrypto) support for manually blinding and unblinding messages. Instead they ask you to specifically pick one of the supported padding schemes, as is done in the sample code in your question.

Now of course, if you are looking for actual [blind signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature) as per your tag, then it seems that you'll have to move away from PyCrypto(dome), as they no longer support that. In fact there seems to be no out-of-the-box support in any of the big Python cryptographic libraries, based on a cursory search.

Comment: Hi, yes, you are correct. I am actually using the PyCrypto Py3 fork, PyCryptodome. I guess my question was surrounding this. In the Py2 version there were these methods, which have subsequently been removed.

Is there a way to replicate blinding? I understand one method would be for a sender to send N-many duplicate messages, and the signer will "blindly" sign one of many of these messages, assuming that it is likely to not be frauduent. Would signing essentially be the same as the receiving address using their private key to sign the message?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Blind signatures allow you to get a signature of a message without the **signing** party knowing what message they signed. Thus it is the party which **receives** a signature which does the blinding and unblinding operations. The signing party simply signs a (blinded) message as it normally would.

Comment: Sure, so I'm trying to find a way for a user to send a message saying, {"deposit": 1000, "id": {random_integer}}. Then, yes, the receiving party will sign this message, however the receiving party will not be able to see the contents of the message prior to signing. Therefore, if the user were to send N-many dupes of this message, the receiving party could peak at all messages sent, bar one. This is the one which would be signed blind.

Comment: With blind signatures, the signing party will not be able to look at the message it signed, until the time the receiving party chooses to reveal its unblinded signature. Thus that might be a tool for you to use. I'm not clear on your 'send N and peak at all except one' approach would work.

What you might want to do is - precisely - describe the problem you are actually trying to solve. Then people can provide advise on how to do that.